# Dynamically Changing Bar Chart Colors

Tags: python, colors, bar-chart

I have time series data that I am trying to create a series of separate bar charts for. My bar charts include both historical and forecast data, and I would like the historical data in one color, and the forecast data in another. The kicker here is that I will need to change the time frame for these bar charts depending on client need. I currently have the colors hard coded in based on the current time frame that I'm using (defined in the timeframe and timeframe1 df's to affect both the levels df and percentage change df), but I would like the colors to automatically shift as I change the time frame that I'm looking at to always have historical data in one color and forecast in another. Is this possible in Python?

Here is what I currently have:

```
names = ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3" ]
colors = ['#3f4faa', '#3f4faa','#3f4faa', '#3f4faa', '#3f4faa', '#ff573b', '#ff573b', '#ff573b' ]
timeframe = state["2019":"2026"]
timeframe1 = statepc["2019":"2026"]


for i, names in zip(timeframe.columns, names):
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        barplot = plt.bar(timeframe.index, timeframe[i], color = colors)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.ylabel('A')
        plt.bar_label(barplot, labels=timeframe1[i].round(1).astype(str).add('%'), label_type= "edge")
        plt.title(names)
```

Comment: You should be able to use a Pandas dataframe with Seaborn for this.